# two conditions in one column and another condition in another column to make a new column in R

Tags: r

```
    df$A(12, 12, 17, 17, 17, 99, 99, 56, 56, 56, 13, 13, 13, 89, 89, 89)
df$C(Aplus, Bplus, Aplus, A,  Aplus, Dplus, A,  A,  Cminus, Dplus, Aplus, A,  Dplus, Aminus, Aplus, Dplus)
df$D(mt, mt, mt, wt, wt, mt, mt, wt, wt, wt, mt, wt, wt, wt, mt, wt)
```

I would like to create a new column E on the bottom in which the following are true.

WT Aplus equal to mt and Bplus

SS A equal to wt, Cminus equal to wt, Dplus equal to wt

HH Aplus equal to mt or Dplus

```
df$E(WT, WT, NA, NA, NA, HH, NA, SS, SS, SS, HH, NA, HH, NA, HH, HH)


df1 <- df %>% mutate(E = ifelse(D %in% c("A+" & "B+") & E == "mt", "WT"))
df1 <- df %>% mutate(E = ifelse(D %in% c("A" & "C-" & "D+") == "wt", "SS"))
df1 <- df %>% mutate(E = ifelse(D %in% c("A+" & "D+"), "HH"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am unable to get the df$E output stated above. Instead for the first line of code that I run to implement WT Aplus equal to mt and Bplus, I get this output of 5 WT instead of 2 WT

```
df$E(WT, WT, WT, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, WT, NA, NA, NA, WT, NA)
```

Comment: Change to `D %in% c("A+", "B+") & E == "mt"`. The `%in%` infix operator takes a vector of *values* as its second (RHS) argument, not a `logical` vector like you are trying (and incorrectly) to produce with `"A+" & "B+"`.

Comment: Also, `ifelse` (and `dplyr::if_else` and `data.table::fifelse`) *requires* three arguments: the `test=`, which is the conditional; `yes=`, which you have provided as `"WT"` and `"SS"` and `"HH"`; and `no=`, which you have omitted. I suspect you were seeing an error of `argument "no" is missing, with no default`. Really, if you get errors with your code, please include them in your question. If you aren't getting errors, then ... something else is really really wrong here.

Comment: Lastly, when you include code and reproducible data in your question, it needs to be *usable* and *syntactically correct* code. The first code block here is not correct R code. While we can *infer* what you might be intending there, it is often difficult differentiating between typos in the question and actual errors in your code, as both appear here.

Comment: Ummm .... *how has it been fixed?* In what dialect of R is `df$A(12,12,17)` a valid method for defining a column? The only time that is syntactically correct code is if there is a named list named `df`, and in that list is an element named `A` that is a function that accepts numeric arguments. **Please** [edit] your question and paste the output from `dput(head(df,10))` into the first code block.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `case_when` for multiple conditions

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(E = case_when(D %in%  c("A+", "B+") &  E == 'mt' ~ 'WT',
                         D %in% c("A", 'C-', 'D+') == 'wt' ~ 'SS',
                         D %in% c('A+', 'D+') ~ "HH"))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, the code you provide with "," instead of "&" is still giving me the wrong output in which all A+ mt have to output of WT.

Comment: @vcat Can you update your post with a small reproducible example using `dput` and your expected ouptut so that it can be tested. thanks.  Also, your `na` I expect to be `NA`

Comment: Should be "reproducible" now.  Also I have tried using group_by(A), but I get the same output with 5 WT.

Comment: @vcat Sorry, I meant `dput`.  If i check your code, it is still not in a rpeorudcible example.  can you try `dput(head(df))` and get the output to your post